# Text is concentrated on the left

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, wrapfigure, russian

I know that the distortion arose because of the image, but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}


%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы


%%% Изменение шрифта
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Computer Modern Sans Serif
\newcommand{\highMax}[1]{\Large{\textcolor{purple}{\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\highMed}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{purple}{\textbf{#1}}}}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%%% Таблицы 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}

%%% Работа с картинками
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Для вставки рисунков
\graphicspath{{img/}}  % папки с картинками
\setlength\fboxsep{3pt} % Отступ рамки \fbox{} от рисунка
\setlength\fboxrule{1pt} % Толщина линий рамки \fbox{}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Обтекание рисунков и таблиц текстом
\usepackage{watermark} % Фон

%%% ссылки
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{noto-serif}
\usepackage{noto-sans}
\usepackage{noto-mono}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty} % отключение нумерации страниц

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry} % Изменение полей


\begin{document} % Конец преамбулы, начало текста.  
    
    
    \hrule
    \section*{\Huge{Кхалиф}}
    \hrule
    
    
    
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim=0pt 0pt 0pt 45pt]{ava.png}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    
    \vspace{3.5cm}
    
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.4\textwidth} p{1\textwidth}}
            \highMax{Прозвище}: & Монах\\
            \highMax{Пол}:      & Мужской\\
            \highMax{Раса}:     & Человек (3/10 дроу)\\
            \highMax{Возраст}:  & 21 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \vspace{4.6cm}
    \hrule



    
    \begin{tabular}{p{15cm} c}  
        \subsection*{Биография}
    \end{tabular}
    
    Родившись в восходящей торговой столице в первые же часы он оказался на пороге новообразованного дома для детей без родителей ()
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a lot of redundancies and several outright conflicts. It also misuses/misappropriates a few standard LaTeX commands, such as `\section*`.

I'm afraid I can't read Cyrillic text very well, but I think that the following may be close to what you're trying to achieve. Observe that the code doesn't make use of the `wrapfigure` machinery.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}

%%%% Работа с русским языком
%\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
%\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы

%\usepackage{polyglossia} % Don't load both polyglossia and babel
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
%%%\setmainfont{Arial} % this gets overwritten later

%%% ссылки
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{noto-serif}
\usepackage{noto-sans}
\usepackage{noto-mono}

%%% Изменение шрифта
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % "Computer Modern" -- why??

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\highMax}[1]{{\Large\textcolor{purple}{\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\highMed}[1]{\textcolor{purple}{\textbf{#1}}}

%%% Таблицы 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}

%%% Работа с картинками
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  %% remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\graphicspath{{img/}}  % папки с картинками
\setlength\fboxsep{3pt} % Отступ рамки \fbox{} от рисунка
\setlength\fboxrule{1pt} % Толщина линий рамки \fbox{}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Обтекание рисунков и таблиц текстом
\usepackage{watermark} % Фон

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty} % отключение нумерации страниц

\usepackage[margin=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry} % Изменение полей


\begin{document} % Конец преамбулы, начало текста.     
    
    \hrule
    \begin{center}
    \Huge\bfseries Кхалиф
    \end{center}
    \hrule
    
    \vspace{3.5cm}
    
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
            \highMax{Прозвище} & Монах\\
            \highMax{Пол}      & Мужской\\
            \highMax{Раса}     & Человек (3/10 дроу)\\
            \highMax{Возраст}  & 21 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim=0pt 0pt 0pt 45pt]{ava.png}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \vspace{4.6cm}
    \hrule
    
    %\begin{tabular}{p{15cm} c}  
    \subsection*{Биография}
    %\end{tabular}
    
    Родившись в восходящей торговой столице в первые же часы он 
    оказался на пороге новообразованного дома для детей без 
    родителей ()
   
\end{document}
```